# How to hide iOS Keyboard with Leadfoot / Appium / Webdriver?

Tags: webdriver, intern, leadfoot

Does anyone know how to hide the iOS keyboard on Appium (latest: v1.4.1) using Leadfoot / Intern? I'd hoped that:

```
.deactivateIme()
```

...would dismiss the keyboard but I get

```
Starting tunnel...
Initialised iOS on MAC 8.1
Test main - Suite Name - Login Screen FAILED on iOS on MAC 8.1:
UnknownCommand: [POST http://192.168.158:4723/wd/hub/session/410a4e1e-b886-4e2a-aec0-f1c5178577e4/ime/deactivate] **Not yet implemented**
```

Which is fairly clear why .deactivateIme() isn't working.